# CSV split rows into lists

Tags: python, list, csv

So i would like to split string from list into multiple lists 
like rows[1] should be splited into another list contained in list m
i saw this here and it hsould be accesable m[0][0] to get first item form first list . 
    import csv

```
reader = csv.reader(open("alerts.csv"), delimiter=',')
)
rows=[]
for row in reader:
    rows.append(row)

num_lists=int(len(rows))
lists=[]


m=[]

for x in rows:
    m.append(x.split(';')[0])
```

printing rows:

```
[['priority;status;time;object_class;host;app;inc;tool;msg'], ['P2;CLOSED;24-09-2016 20:06:41;nm;prod;;390949;HPNNM;call'], ['P2;CLOSED;24-09-2016 20:06:41;nm;prod;;390949;HPNNM;msg'], ['P2;CLOSED;24-09-2016 20:06:41;nm;prod;;390949;HPNNM;msg']]
```

and output should look like 
m[0][0] should return pririty

Comment: Change your delimiter to ``;`` (1st line of your script)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this pretty easily with pandas

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv')

for x in A.values:
    for y in x:
        print y
```

so the 'print y' statement access each element in the row.  but I  mean, after the "for x in A.values" you can do just about anything

Comment: *A bit* overkill, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Exact solution to your question; you almost got it right (note the `delimiter` value):

```
reader = csv.reader(open("alerts.csv"), delimiter=';')
table = [row for row in reader]
print(table[0][0])

>>> priority
```

For easy data handling, it is often nice to explicitly extract the header like so:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("alerts.csv"), delimiter=';')
header = reader.next()
table = [row for row in reader]
print(header[0])
print(table[0][0])

>>> priority
>>> P2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it:

```
import csv

with open('alerts.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader)    # skip over the first header row
    rows = [row for row in reader]

>>> print(rows[0][0])
P2
```

This uses a list comprehension to read all rows from the CSV file into a list. The delimiter should be a semi-colon, not a comma; so use `delimiter=';'`. Also the first row is a header and is therefore skipped.